# How to use ArrayLists in ListAdapter (ListView)?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

)

I found a tutorial about using the ListView in android. But I have a question about it. Here the tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive

You have to scroll to section 13.2.

The idea of the tutorial is on one hand you have a ListView (with checkboxes in each item), on the other hand you have an ArrayList (the items of the ArrayList are objects, which contain the information which are displayed in the items of the ListView, e.g. CheckBox checked or not, text etc.). The adapter schould keep both things equal. If you change the ArrayList, the ListView will be changed, too.

But now my question. If the user touch on one item of the List, the adapter will call the method "onCheckedChanged". But what happen there? An object will create there and get a tag from the the CheckBox. Ok. Now the method is done. The garbage collector will destroy the object or doesn't? What is when I need this infomation from there in my Activity. Imagine I have a button "Delete" under my list. So I have to transfer these information from the listener of the adapter to my Activity. How I can ensure that I use the same ArrayList with the right information in every class?

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
          Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
              .getTag();
          element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

        }
```

I hope you know what I mean. Can you explain it to me please?

Sorry for the language, but english isn't my mother tongue.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the response is in the Chapter 14.1 of the tutorial you gaved...

If you want to do some treatment when delete is checked you add a listener in the ListView.

These functions normally have the position clicked and you can do whatever you want knowing the position clicked. For exemple:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(MyList.this,
        "Item in position " + position + " clicked",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Return true to consume the click event. In this case the
    // onListItemClick listener is not called anymore.
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But in my opinion you are just able to use onItemClickListener when the Activity extended by ListActivity. When the ListView is just part of a layout, so you can't use ListActivity, right? My question was why they create an object in "onCheckedChanged", when the object will destroy at the end of the method and they never use it again in the code?

Comment: They used the variable to do the cast and to make the code a little bit more legible... It's easier to read as they have rather than ((Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag()).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked())

Comment: And you can use the listener every time you use a ListView, in the case I showed the variable list is a ListView...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand you're question. There's a lot to unpack in there but I will give it a shot. To understand what's going on you need to understand the relationship between the `ListView` and the data that backs it which is contained in the `ListAdapter`.

The `ListView` displays the data contained in the `ListAdapter`. The `ListAdapter` gets its data from some other source, in this case its the `ArrayList` that you're referring to. Why use an `ArrayList`? In the tutorial its not entirely clear because the example uses a fixed set of data (e.g. a list of operating systems) that are written out as strings. In practice, however, often times you are using a dynamic list, like a list of users, places, whatever.

The `ArrayList` holds the objects that will eventually be displayed. This is the "models" class in the tutorial. The same applies for any other class of data, like a list of places. If you imagine a place as a class, that class would contain fields that describe the place (e.g. address, a description, some other unique features). As data is downloaded from some location, a new instance of place would be created for each location. Those objects would be collected in an `ArrayList`. When the downaloding process was finished, you would then begin the process of passing the contents of that `ArrayList` to the `ListAdapter` so that the `ListView` could eventually be updated.

How do you know you will always use the right `ArrayList`? Because your `ArrayList` is linked to you `ListAdapter`. The data the the `ListAdapter` processes, whether a list of models or users, is supplied by the `ArrayList`. You cannot use the wrong one. The same goes for the `ListAdapter`. Because you must set the adapter that the `ListView` is linked it it will always pull from the correct source. You cannot use the wrong data.

What's happening with the `onCheckChanged` listener, if you pay close attention, is that the user is really just updating a field contained in the model class. Each modle has an isChecked field. When the check box is clicked, that value for the object is updated. This is how you know what is checked and what is not.

**Response to: "Nobody told the adapter "Hey it belongs to the list, which is your source"**

Look at the documentation for [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)
and for [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)

The constructors for the `ArrayAdapter` all take some list of object as an argument. This list would be the list of object that will be displayed within the `ListView`.

Additionally the `ListView` requires that you call `setAdapter` which takes some `ListAdapter` as its argument. This is what actually tells the `ListView` the source of the data it is going to display.

In that sense, the `List`, `ListAdapter`, and `ListView` are all linked together.

Comment: Thank you very much for this good explanation. I understand it. But where is the line where the List were connected to the Adapter? In the activity the List is sended to the adapter. Then the constructor of the adapter write the list in the list-variable "list". That's all. How the adapter knows "Thats my source"? Or is that happen in the background because the superclass gets the list, too? Next question: how the adapter knows that "element" belongs to the source "list"? It is a new object generate in the method "onCheckedChanged".

Comment: Nobody told the adapter "Hey it belongs to the list, which is your source".

Comment: I think now I understand. They don't change the list in "onCheckedChanged". They modify just the tag of the checkbox. Is that right? Anyway, for example I have in my list objects with two information "Title" and "checked". The "Title" get his String from a EditBox, e.g. "Test", when the user press OK-Button. After that there is an object in my list with the information "Test" and "0", because the checkbox isn't checked. Now I have an item "Test" in my ListView with an unchecked Checkbox on my screen of my mobile phone. After this the user touch the Checkbox.

Comment: Now it is activate. The method "onCheckedChanged" in the Adapter will be execute. How can I update my list now?

Comment: What do you mean? Update the `ListView`? Please be more specific, there are a lot of list terms flying around here.